# Java set data to JTable from database

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable, tablemodel

i try to insert data from database to Jtable 
there is my code:

```
private Vector <Vector<String>> data;
private Vector<String> header;
table.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
data,header     
));

GtFromDb db=new GtFromDb();
data=db.getClient();

header=new Vector<String>();
header.add("Imones pavadinimas");
header.add("vardas");
header.add("pavarde");
header.add("salis");
header.add("Adresas");
header.add("telefonas");

public Vector getClient() 
{
    Vector <Vector<String>> clientVector=new Vector<Vector<String>>();  
    try
    {
         PreparedStatement zadanie = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Clients");
         dane = zadanie.executeQuery();
         while(dane.next()) {
             Vector <String> client=new Vector<String>();
             String imonesPav=dane.getString("Imones_pavadinimas");
             String vardas = dane.getString("Vardas");
             String pavarde = dane.getString("Pavarde");
             String salis = dane.getString("Salis");
             String adresas=dane.getString("Adresas");
             String telefonas = dane.getString("Telefonas");
             if (imonesPav != null) {
                 imonesPav = imonesPav.trim();
                 client.add(imonesPav);
             }
             if (vardas != null) {
                 vardas = vardas.trim();
                 client.add(vardas);
             }
             if (pavarde != null) {
                 pavarde = pavarde.trim();
                 client.add(pavarde);
             }
             if (salis != null) {
                 salis = salis.trim();
                 client.add(salis);
             }
             if (adresas != null) {
                 adresas = adresas.trim();
                 client.add(adresas);
             }
             if (telefonas != null) {
                 telefonas = telefonas.trim();
                 client.add(telefonas);
             }
        }
        zadanie.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e){}
        return clientVector;    
    }
```

it thorows me error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at test$GtFromDb.getClient(test.java:108)
at test.<init>(test.java:49)
at test.main(test.java:24)
```

where is problem?

Comment: There is not enough information. What line exactly corresponds to the test.java:108 ?

Comment: PreparedStatement zadanie = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Clients");

Comment: So connect is null. Where are you instantiating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to added and another ...

1) `client=new Vector<String>();` to the `DefaultTableModel` inside loop `while(dane.next()) {...}`

2) `public Vector getClient()` must be initialized return null

3) change `public Vector getClient()` to `public void getClient()`, remove return statement

4) `PreparedStatement zadanie` must be closed in `finally` block `try- catch - finally`

5) `dane = zadanie.executeQuery();` looks like as Resultset, and same as `PreparedStatement zadanie` must be closed in `finally` block

6) `JTable` and `Vector` can hold `null value`

7) if you are only to want to display data from `DbTable` to the `JTable` then look for `ResultsetTableModel`, `TableFromDatabase`, you can search for that on this forum too

Answer (score -1):

Try these Codes Structure But in yours :

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
dtm.setColumnCount(2);
dtm.setRowCount(2);
dtm.setValueAt("Imones pavadinimas", 1, 1);
dtm.setValueAt("Imones vardas", 2, 1);
dtm.setValueAt("Pavarde", 1, 2);
dtm.setValueAt("Salis", 2, 2);
 ...
jTable1.setModel(dtm);
```

Comment: Some additional explanations about this code you probably be helpful.